# Double FAB buttons showing on initial launch

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing Flutter app and added a FAB button in centre at bottom navigation bar. But when I launch app I found 2 separate FAB buttons showing.

I am using following code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text("itsmee."),
      ),
      drawer: sideDrawer(),
      body: _loadTabbedScreen(),
      bottomNavigationBar: FABBottomAppBar(
//        centerItemText: 'A',
        color: Colors.grey,
        selectedColor: Colors.red,
        notchedShape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        onTabSelected: _selectedTab,
        items: [
          FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.home, text: 'Home'),
          FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.search, text: 'Search'),
          FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.favorite, text: 'Review'),
          FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.person, text: 'Profile'),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: _buildFab(context), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

For reference I am adding screenshot of app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using both `BottomNavigationBar` and likely `Scaffold` too.  Take a look at where your `Scaffold` is defined as that's whee the `FAB` over the `Profile` is created.